# Improving elasticsearch performance

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch in a python web app in order to query news documents. There're actually 100000 documents in the database.

The original db is a mongo one and elasticsearch is plugged through the mongoriver plugin.

The problem is that the function takes ~850ms to return the results. I'd like to decrease that number as much as possible.

Here's  the python code I'm using to query the db(the limit is usually 16):

```
def search_news(term, limit, page, flagged_articles):
    query = {

        "query": {
            "from": page*limit,
            "size": limit,
            "multi_match" : {
                "query" : term,
                "fields" : [ "title^3" , "category^5" , "entities.name^5", "art_text^1", "summary^1"]
            }
        },
        "filter" : {
            "not" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "ids" : {
                        "values" : flagged_articles
                    }
                },
                "_cache" : True
            }
        }
    }

    es_query = json_util.dumps(query)

    uri = 'http://localhost:9200/newsidx/_search'
    r = requests.get(uri, data=es_query)

    results = json.loads( r.text )
    data = []
    for res in results['hits']['hits']:
        data.append(res['_source'])

    return data
```

And here's the index mapping:

```
  {
  "news": {
    "properties": {
      "actual_rank": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "added": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "api_id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "art_text": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "downvotes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "entities": {
        "properties": {
          "etype": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "flags": {
        "properties": {
          "a": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "b": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "bad_image": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "c": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "d": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "innapropiate": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "irrelevant_info": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "miscategorized": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "media": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "published": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "published_date": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "show": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "source_rank": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "summary": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "times_showed": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "top_entities": {
        "properties": {
          "einfo_test": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "etype": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "tweet_article_poster": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "tweet_favourites": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "tweet_retweets": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "tweet_user_rank": {
        "type": "double"
      },
      "upvotes": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: The response time was measured on the server, given the tornado server information output.

Comment: Can you pretty print that mapping? It's hard to make sense of.

Comment: Do you have enough memory? Have you devoted at least 50% of your memory to the Java Heap? Related, how many replicas do you have? If you have 2+, and if you're having memory problems, consider reducing replicas.

Comment: How did you measure the response time? Is it end-to-end or the time returned by elasticsearch itself (`took` field)?

Comment: Just from the look on it I have the feeling that the problem is not the query or the mapping. As suggested check you allocated memory for ES etc.. Look into other performance boosts on how to tweak ES. Maybe this helps: http://www.slideshare.net/kucrafal/scaling-massive-elastic-search-clusters-rafa-ku-sematext

Comment: Try to run the Node Diagnostic of ElasticHQ, it can detect bad node behavior: http://www.elastichq.org/app/index.php#nodediagnostics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rewritten your query somewhat here, moving the `size` and `limit` to the outside scope, adding the `filtered` query clause and changing your `not` query to a `bool`/`must_not` query, which should be cached by default:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match" : {
                    "query" : term,
                    "fields" : [ "title^3" , "category^5" , "entities.name^5", "art_text^1", "summary^1"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must_not" : {
                        "ids" : {"values" : flagged_articles}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    "from": page * limit,
    "size": limit,
}
```

I haven't tested this, and I haven't made sense of your mapping as it is jumbled, so there might be some improvements to be made there.

Edit: This is a great read on why to use the `bool` filter: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/ - in short, `bool` uses 'bitsets', which are very fast on subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can add the boosts to your mapping (assuming it doesn't interfere with your other queries) like this:

```
"title": {
  "boost": 3.0,
  "type": "string"
},
"category": {
  "boost": 5.0,
  "type": "string"
},
etc.
```

Then setup a bool query with field (or term) queries like this:

```
"query": {
  "bool" : {
    "should" : [ {
      "field" : {
        "title" : term
      }
    }, {
      "field" : {
        "category" : term
      }
    } ],
    "must_not" : {
      "ids" : {"values" : flagged_articles}
    }
  }
} 
"from": page * limit,
"size": limit
```

This should perform better, but without access to your setup I can't test it :)